# Is there a way in Haskell to check whether a module exports the same functions as an other one?

Tags: haskell

I have some specs (written with HSpec) and would like to have a test that checks whether the re-exporting of some functions takes place as intended.

Code:

https://github.com/Wizek/compose-ltr/blob/ab954f00beb56c6c1a595261381d40e7e824e3bc/spec/Spec.hs#L4

If I go into this file, I can run all tests with either import if I manually switch whether line 4 or 5 is commented out. Is there a simple way to have an automated specification that ensures that both modules export the same functions?

The first thing I thought of is to import one of the modules qualified, and check for equality:

```
(($>) == (ComposeLTR.$>)) `shouldBe` True
-- Or more succintly
($>) `shouldBe` (ComposeLTR.$>)
```

But that won't work since functions are not directly comparable, they are not part of the `Eq` type class.

The only thing I can think of that would work automatically is to import qualified and to define QuickCheck properties for all 4 functions like so:

```
import qualified ComposeLTR

it "should re-export the same function" $ do
  let
    prop :: (Fun Int Int) -> Int -> Bool
    prop (Fun _ f) g = (g $> f) == (g ComposeLTR.$> f)
  property prop

-- ... Essentially repeated 3 more times
```

But that seems awfully long-handed and redundant. Is there an elegant way to check this?

Comment: Even if functions had an `Eq` instance it would be a useless instance. Function equality is undecidable and so it would return wrong results, no matter how it is implemented.

Comment: Not necessarily. Equality could be checked for the trivial case, which would be useful in my specific case: `fn == fn`, or less trivially: `let fn' = fn in fn == fn'`. So in these cases, the pointers to these functions are identical, AFAIU, and those can be compared. For example functions can be compared like this in JavaScript; if it returns true, you can be sure they are the same. If it returns false, they may still behave identically, but we at least know that their pointers point to different memory addresses.

Comment: You invoke “JavaScript does it” as a reason that something should be possible in Haskell – [seriously](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)? No, really, apart from totally not being in the spirit of Haskell, to replace equality with pointer equality would also not be very useful: because values are so often re-wrapped, re-arranged, identity-composed etc.. All of that will break pointer equality though it's structure-preserving. — To check whether different modules export the same stuff, surely the correct solution would operate on the syntax/module level, not on the value level?

Comment: Besides, pointer equality would break referential transparency, making it both useless and illegal.

Comment: That's an interesting point @ReinHenrichs, could you give an example on how it would break referential transparency?

Comment: It does so literally, by making the reference no longer transparent. It means I can't replace `id foo` with `foo` and yield an equivalent program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StableName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html)s in IO:

```
Prelude Data.List System.Mem.StableName> v  <- makeStableName   Prelude.takeWhile
Prelude Data.List System.Mem.StableName> v' <- makeStableName Data.List.takeWhile
Prelude Data.List System.Mem.StableName> v == v'
True
```

Comment: For a certain definition of "beautiful" that's beautiful!